# Chef, where to store "support" data for recipes/roles?

Tags: chef-infra

i would call my self beginner with Chef and currently would like to ask what is the best practice for storing information for chefs use(not sensitive).

I will give example:

1) In order for one recipe to run correctly i had to have information about environments and which machines are in the environment.
So i did created json and put it to cookbook/files.

```
#cookbook/files
        {
          "UAT1" : [
           "hostname1",
           "hostname2",
           ],
          "DEV2" : [
           "hostname3",
           "hostname4", 
           "hostname5"
           ]
       }
```

Then in the recipe i create this json on the node , and read from it when chef runs to see if i can find this hostname in the json and if yes, set attribute that i use in template later.

```
cookbook_file 'hostnames.json' do
  path '/hostnames.json'
  source 'hostnames.json'
  owner USER
  group GROUP
end.run_action(:create)

json = File.read('/hostnames.json')
hostname_list = JSON.parse(json)

hostname_list.each do |env, hostnames|
  hostnames.each do |host|
    node.default['environment'] = env if hostname == host
  end
end
```

**Questions:**

a) Can i read from files in cookbook without creating it actually? Because the way i am doing it right now doesnt feel right.

b) Is there any other/preferred way to store information?I have used data bags but i think its not the case, or it is?

I know question is wide, so tldr would be, what is your way of storing information that you need to use in chef run?

Answer (score 0):

`file` or `template` resources are for managing files on the target machine, and not storing some meta information for the chef-client run.

This kind of information can be taken from 3 places: search, attributes and data bags. ([Chef attributes versus data bags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15273302/170230))

In your case actually, you need to specify the node's environment at the bootstrap. So when you bootstrap *hostname1* add another parameter to [*knife* command](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_bootstrap/):

```sh
knife bootstrap [...] --environment UAT1
```

This will set `node['chef_environment']` value on the node.

If some node actually requires a list of nodes, that belong to some environment, this can be found using [search](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search/)

```rb
# recipe
uat1_nodes = search(:node, 'chef_environment:UAT1')
```

This would be the preferred way. If it does not suite you, then the place to store this information is a data bag. This way you can get your data, without this dancing with a tambourine:

```rb
# data bag item
{
  "id": "myhosts",
  "UAT1" : [
    "hostname1",
    "hostname2",
  ],
  "DEV2" : [
    "hostname3",
    "hostname4", 
    "hostname5"
  ]
}
# recipe
hostname_list = data_bag_item('<data_bag_name>', 'myhosts')
hostname_list.each do |env, hostnames|
  hostnames.each do |host|
    node.default['environment'] = env if hostname == host
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you ! i i somehow thought data bags are for sensitive info. Thanks again

Comment: Not necessarily. Encrypted data bags are for sensitive info, but plain data bags can be used for anything.